React add and edit record using data grid
trying to follow the React tutorial at the following link to CRUD data but can't find why my code getAction does not receive any 'id' because of that isInEditMode is not true so my button doesn't change to Save and Cancel

import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {  Box, Typography,} from '@mui/material';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined';
import SaveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Save';
import CancelIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import EditToolbar from './EditToolbar';

import {
  GridRowModes,
  DataGrid,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridActionsCellItem,
  GridRowEditStopReasons,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const AdminView = ()=> {
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);
  const [rowModesModel, setRowModesModel] = React.useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch user data from the database using Axios
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/users')
    
      .then(response => {
        setRows(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
      });
  }, []);
  
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    { field: "id"},
    { field: "staff_number", editable: true },
    { field: "name", editable: true },
    { field: "surname", editable: true },
    { field: "email", editable: true  },
    { field: "password", editable: true },
    { field: "access_level", editable: true },
    {
      field: 'actions',
      type: 'actions',
      headerName: 'Actions',
      width: 100,
      cellClassName: 'actions',
      getActions: ({ id }) => {
        console.log('get action:', rowModesModel[id]);
        const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit;

        if (isInEditMode) {
          return [
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<SaveIcon />}
              label="Save"
              sx={{
                color: 'primary.main',
              }}
              onClick={handleSaveClick(id)}
            />,
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<CancelIcon />}
              label="Cancel"
              className="textPrimary"
              onClick={handleCancelClick(id)}
              color="inherit"
            />,
          ];
        }

        return [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<EditIcon />}
            label="Edit"
            className="textPrimary"
            onClick={handleEditClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<DeleteIcon />}
            label="Delete"
            onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
        ];
      },
    }
  ]); 

  const handleEditClick = (id) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit } });
  };
  const handleSaveClick = (id) => () => {
    console.log('handleSaveClick:', id);
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View } });
  };
  const handleDeleteClick = (id) => () => {
    setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
  };

  const handleCancelClick = (id) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({
      ...rowModesModel,
      [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View, ignoreModifications: true },
    });

    const editedRow = rows.find((row) => row.id === id);
    if (editedRow.isNew) {
      setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
    }
  };



  const handleModeRowsChange = (newRowModesModel ) => {
    console.log('newRowModesModel change to:', newRowModesModel);
    setRowModesModel(newRowModesModel);
  }
  const handleRowEditStop = (params, event) => {
    console.log('handleRowEditStop params:', params);
    if (params.reason === GridRowEditStopReasons.rowFocusOut) {
      event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
    }
  };

  const processRowUpdate = (newRow) => {
    console.log('processRowUpdate newRow returned:', newRow);
    const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
    setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
    console.log('updatedRow returned:', updatedRow);
    return updatedRow;
  };

  return (

        <div>
            <DataGrid
              rows={rows}
              columns={columns}
              editMode="row" // allow all row edit
              checkboxSelection
              rowModesModel={rowModesModel} // control modes of rows
              onRowModesModelChange={handleModeRowsChange} // set the variable to control the row modes rowModesModel edit, view, add
              onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop} // stop the edit mode
              processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
              slots={{
                toolbar: EditToolbar,
              }}
              slotProps={{
                toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel },
              }}
            />
        </div>

  );
};

export default AdminView;


my tooldbar button
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined';
import SaveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Save';
import CancelIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import {
  GridRowModes,
  DataGrid,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridActionsCellItem,
  GridRowEditStopReasons,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import {
  randomCreatedDate,
  randomTraderName,
  randomId,
  randomArrayItem,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';


function EditToolbar(props) {
  const { setRows, setRowModesModel } = props;

  const handleClick = () => {
    // Generate a unique ID for the new row.
    const id = randomId();  // Ensure `randomId` is a function that returns a unique ID.
  
    // Add a new row at the end of the grid with empty fields.
    setRows((oldRows) => [
      ...oldRows,  // Keep all existing rows.
      {
        id,  // Assign the new unique ID.
        name: '',  // Start with an empty name.
        surname: '',  // Start with an empty surname.
        email: '',  // Start with an empty email.
        password: '',  // Start with an empty password.
        access_level: '',  // Start with an empty access level.
        staff_number: '',  // Start with an empty staff number.
        isNew: true  // Flag this row as new for special handling like focusing.
      }
    ]);
  
    // Set the new row to be in edit mode, focusing on the 'staff_number' field.
    setRowModesModel((oldModel) => ({
      ...oldModel,  // Keep all existing row modes.
      [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit, fieldToFocus: 'staff_number' }  // Set the new row to edit mode.
    }));
  };

  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <Button color="primary" startIcon={<AddIcon />} onClick={handleClick}>
        Add record
      </Button>
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}

export default EditToolbar;



Do not wrap columns into useState - just initiate them as regular const
const columns = [
    { field: "id"},
    { field: "staff_number", editable: true }
...
]

